# Помогите вышла одна ошибка

Tags: python, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так я начинающий bakend программист по что учусь нам задали домашнее задание, а когда я его разрабатывал выскочила эта ошибка. Как ее исправить я уже даже perplexity.ai ии использовал но походу я вопросы не умею задавать. Он мне предложил из ссылки сделать строку я попробовал но не вышло поэтому прошу помогите.

Comment: Приведите [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из-за того, что вы что-то парсите, в переменную попадает не текст, а значение типа "Tag".

Comment: спасибо большое